Update table if the count of distinct value is less than or equal to 5
I am creating a script wherein I need to update the table and set the STATUS to 'A' with conditions:

if the status is equal to 'N' and

if the count of distinct ID is less than or equal to 5.


I have found a workaround that could help me with my problem. However, I am getting an error, and I am not sure how to solve it.
TableName: TB_ABCD
---------------------
ID        |   STATUS
---------------------
11111     |  N
11111     |  N
11111     |  Y
22222     |  N
22222     |  N
33333     |  Y
44444     |  N
44444     |  N
55555     |  Y
55555     |  Y
---------------------

Expected output:
---------------------
ID        |   STATUS
---------------------
11111     |  A
11111     |  A
11111     |  Y
22222     |  A
22222     |  A
33333     |  Y
44444     |  A
44444     |  A
55555     |  Y
55555     |  Y
---------------------

I am using SQL Developer and the query is like this:
with cteData as (
select count(distinct (case when status='N' then ID end)) as rn from tb_abcd
)
update cteData set status='A' where rn <= 5;

I cannot compile due to the error in update line statement. The error says: "Syntax error. Partially recognized rules (railroad diagrams).
How do I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance for you help.

Can you also specify the expected result, i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

As an aside, "Partially recognized rules" is a warning SQL Developer shows, sometimes errantly. It's much more helpful to execute the statement and include the error that produces - which here is ORA-00928 because your CTE has to be followed by select not update.

@jarlh - I've added the expected output for your reference. Thank you.

Try this approach, which uses a subquery to find the counts of each ID:
UPDATE tb_abcd t1
SET STATUS = 'A'
WHERE STATUS = 'N' AND
    (SELECT cnt FROM
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tb_abcd t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID) t
    ) <= 5;


I've tried your approach, and I am getting 0 rows updated. My table has a total distinct id of 8468.

@user080320 - well 8468 is not less than or equal to 5, so according to the requirement you stated nothing should happen and 0 rows updated is correct. Based on your attempt, maybe you meant "the count of distinct ID with status N is less than or equal to 5"? It's quite hard to tell what you actually want though.

@user080320 The language in your question was ambiguous, and also every ID shown in the sample data has a record count of less than 5.  I have updated my answer to the only thing which seems to make sense for what you asking here.

@TimBiegeleisen - oh yah!correct :). What if, if I want to get the 1st 1000 unique ID records?

What if you want to get the first 1000 unique ID records?  You asked for an update, now you seem to want a select, with some limiting logic.  You should ask a new question.

One option could be to use MERGE INTO for this.
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
CREATE TABLE tbl AS
          Select 11111 "ID", 'Y' "STATUS" From Dual Union All
          Select 11111, 'N' From Dual Union All
          Select 11111, 'Y' From Dual Union All
          Select 22222, 'N' From Dual Union All
          Select 22222, 'N' From Dual Union All
          Select 33333, 'Y' From Dual Union All
          Select 44444, 'N' From Dual Union All
          Select 44444, 'N' From Dual Union All
          Select 55555, 'Y' From Dual Union All
          Select 55555, 'Y' From Dual; 
/*  Table TBL created.  */

--  SQL to fetch IDs that should be updated 
Select Row_Number() Over(Order By t.ID, t.STATUS) "RN", -- row number of distinct ID selected
       t.ID, t.STATUS
From   tbl t
Where  t.STATUS = 'N' AND
       ( Select  CNT 
         From    ( Select  Count(*) "CNT" From  tbl Where   ID = t.ID ) 
       ) <= 5
Group By t.ID, t.STATUS

/*    R e s u l t :
        RN         ID STATUS
---------- ---------- ------
         1      11111 N
         2      22222 N
         3      44444 N       */

The above query could be merged into tbl in order to update matching rows with STATUS = 'N'
MERGE INTO tbl t
USING 
  ( Select Row_Number() Over(Order By t.ID, t.STATUS) "RN", t.ID, t.STATUS
    From   tbl t
    Where  t.STATUS = 'N' AND
          ( Select  CNT 
            From    ( Select  Count(*) "CNT" From  tbl Where   ID = t.ID ) 
          ) <= 5
    Group By t.ID, t.STATUS
  ) x ON(x.ID = t.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t.STATUS = 'A'
WHERE t.STATUS = 'N';
/*  5 rows merged.  */

... testing result
Select * From tbl;
/*
        ID STATUS
---------- ------
     11111 Y
     11111 A
     11111 Y
     22222 A
     22222 A
     33333 Y
     44444 A
     44444 A
     55555 Y
     55555 Y      */

... if you want to limit number of IDs that should be updated (eg. 2) then just add another condition in join's ON clause like below:
MERGE INTO tbl t
USING 
  ( Select Row_Number() Over(Order By t.ID, t.STATUS) "RN", t.ID, t.STATUS
    From   tbl t
    Where  t.STATUS = 'N' AND
          ( Select  CNT 
            From    ( Select  Count(*) "CNT" From  tbl Where   ID = t.ID ) 
          ) <= 5
    Group By t.ID, t.STATUS
  ) x ON(x.ID = t.ID And x.RN <= 2)  -- additional filter on number of distinct IDs to process
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t.STATUS = 'A'
WHERE t.STATUS = 'N';
/*  3 rows merged.  */

... testing result
Select * From tbl;
/*
        ID STATUS
---------- ------
     11111 Y
     11111 A        -- merged  (RN = 1)
     11111 Y
     22222 A        -- merged  (RN = 2)
     22222 A        -- merged  (RN = 2)
     33333 Y
     44444 N        -- NOT merged  (RN = 3)
     44444 N        -- NOT merged  (RN = 3)
     55555 Y
     55555 Y        */

